# The onstorage event doesn't get fired

Tags: javascript

The onstorage event doesn't fire in either Firefox nor Chrome when setting a local storage variable event with a value different than before.

```
window.addEventListener('storage', () => {
    console.log('onStorage raised');
});

//window.onstorage = e => {
//    console.log('onStorage raised');
//}

localStorage.setItem('date', new Date());
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Brobic/fot9vzm6/1/

Comment: Did you write the code that is changing `localStorage`? If so you can always create and trigger your own event.

Answer (score 2):

If you are the one setting `localStorage`, you can create your own event. Although this might be a little overkill as you could always just use this method to call a function also instead of creating an event. I used the older event style since it is more compatible.

```
function setStorage(k, v) {
  const event = document.createEvent('Event');
  event.initEvent('storageChanged', true, true);
  localStorage.setItem(k, v);
  document.dispatchEvent(event);
}

window.addEventListener('storageChanged', (e) => {
  console.log('storageChanged raised');
});

setStorage("date", new Date())

console.log(localStorage.getItem('date'))
```

Answer (score 1):

As written here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/storage_event
Event is fired is storage is changed by ANOTHER document, not self.

Comment: I read that but don't get what it means? What other document? Like an iframe containing another site domain? Wouldn't that be a cross site scripting violation? Or maybe a page other then where the event is declared? This is very confusing.

Comment: Actually I think that is not a cross site violation - it is second tab on the same site. Using this event you have ability for example to show same number for 'items in cart' in multiple online shop pages

Comment: I just tested this by opening the same file twice using localhost each in a different tab. Once I opened the second file, the event was triggered.

Answer (score 0):

As @Quercus pointed out, the event won't fire on it's own page, that's why I use **[localDataStorage](https://github.com/macmcmeans/localDataStorage)**, a handy wrapper for the HTML5 localStorage API that conveniently fires change events *on the same* page/tab/window in which the storage event occurred. (Disclaimer: I am the author of the interface.)

Once you install **localDataStorage**, this sample code will let you see those change events:

```
function nowICanSeeLocalStorageChangeEvents( e ) {
    console.log(
        "subscriber: "    + e.currentTarget.nodeName + "\n" +
        "timestamp: "     + e.detail.timestamp + " (" + new Date( e.detail.timestamp ) + ")" + "\n" +
        "prefix: "        + e.detail.prefix    + "\n" +
        "message: "       + e.detail.message   + "\n" +
        "method: "        + e.detail.method    + "\n" +
        "key: "           + e.detail.key       + "\n" +
        "old value: "     + e.detail.oldval    + "\n" +
        "new value: "     + e.detail.newval    + "\n" +
        "old data type: " + e.detail.oldtype   + "\n" +
        "new data type: " + e.detail.newtype
    );
};
document.addEventListener(
    "localDataStorage"
    , nowICanSeeLocalStorageChangeEvents
    , false
);
```

Answer (score 0):

It works if you have another page that modify the storage

page1.html

```
window.addEventListener('storage', () => {
  console.log('onStorage raised');
});
```

page2.html

```
localStorage.setItem('date', new Date());
```

You can read about at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onstorage